Nuance of フツー　over 普通に?

On the top panel, the character asks for 藤島's "Line", to which 藤島 answers:
"I left it it on the back of the vitamin C drink (I gave you) the other day... Oh I guess you threw it away"
What kind of nuance does フツー here give?

It's #3 What are all the 3 nuances of 普通に? If you don't still see how it fits, you should elaborate why you don't think it fits.

@sundowner I think the question is supposed to be about why it's written in katakana and whether that is supposed to change the interpretation.

It indicates that it's completely normal and natural to throw the package away if the listener didn't know the LINE account was written on it. English expressions similar to this フツーに would be "unsurprisingly", "of course" and "naturally".
